# javascript - calculate "true" keyCode

Tags: javascript, keycode

When I press a key on my keyboard, I can get the keyCode of that key using e.keyCode. But the keyCode I get does not consider the pressed alt/ctrl/shift keys, wich modify the key code.

Fortunately, I get the properties shiftKey/altKey/ctrlKey with the event so I am able to calculate the "true" key code.

But I don't know how to calculate this correctly. Where can I read about that?
Is it as easy as substracting 32 if shift ist pressed and so on, or are there much exceptions?

Comment: There are tons of exceptions, and it gets worse when you take international keyboard layouts into account. Advanced keyboard handling support in javascript is abysmal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken, key codes don't change because they refer to a specific key on the keyboard.  Regardless of modifier keys, those codes stay the same (and even the modifier keys themselves have a key code).

Capture the *keypress* event, which will allow you to access character codes.

```
el.onkeypress = function (evt) {
    alert( (evt || window.event).charCode );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would like to calculate the "true" keyCodes. If you are making shortcuts for your site/app/whatever, you could simply check if the button was pressed was (for example) S and that Ctrl was pressed at the same time.

True keyCodes have no meaning by itself (unless you need it for something specific).

Btw, you should consider using jQuery for your project. It normalizes the keyCodes so you don't have any weird behavior in any browser (Windows and OS). I guess that is more important.

Comment: I need it for a shell, where this is necessary